# Pass key/value pair to Angular filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following template code:

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entries"
     ng-bind-html="ctrl.entry_statuses[entry] | createEntryURL">
</div>
```

where `ctrl.entry_statuses` is an object in the controller that may look like this:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Now, the `createEntryUrl` filter looks something like this:

```
angular.module('test').filter('createEntryURL', function() {
    return function(entry){
        switch(entry){
            case 1:
                return '<span class="one">' + entry + '</span>'
            case 2:
                return '<span class="two">' + entry + '</span>'
            case 3:
                return '<span class="three">' + entry + '</span>'
        }
    }
});
```

As expected, the passed `entry` variable only includes the value part of the key/value pair. Is there any way to pass both the key and value so that I can use the key as a string in the `<span>` and the value to match in the `switch` statement?

The resulting HTML should look like this:

```
<span class="one">a</span>
<span class="two">b</span>
<span class="three">c</span>
```

Comment: Didn't get few things. What object is this `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`? Can you make fiddle/plunker if possible?

Comment: @tanmay The object is what is what is stored in `ctrl.entry_statuses`. Sorry, never tried fiddle/plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pass extra parameter to a custom `filter`, you can use something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entries"
     ng-bind-html="ctrl.entry_statuses[entry] | createEntryURL: entry">
</div>
```

Which will be second argument in your `filter` function. Like this:

```
angular.module('test').filter('createEntryURL', function() {
    return function(entryStatus, entry){ 
        switch(entryStatus){
            case 1:
                return '<span class="one">' + entry + '</span>'
            case 2:
                return '<span class="two">' + entry + '</span>'
            case 3:
                return '<span class="three">' + entry + '</span>'
        }
    }
});
```

Which should result into what you expect:

```
<span class="one">a</span>
<span class="two">b</span>
<span class="three">c</span>
```

Comment: @mart1n glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

Pass the input parameter to filter as below

```
$scope.map[$scope.key]=$scope.value;
$scope.key="";
$scope.value="";
```